# A Funny Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix can rip and tear, pointy or curled, 
>  Where ours mainly grip unless werewolves exist.*
>
> *My suffix is greener in one perfect world. 
>  Some yellow is seen, where some gardens consist.*
>
> *My infix has rules unlike the underworld. 
>  It governs like schools; do not break or resist!*
>
> *And now change the vowel to between the IP. 
>  Or throw in the towel, but that works if you see.*
>
> ***What could I be?***

The answer is just $5$ letters long, and the title *owns a clue*.

Comment: as always a pretty nice riddle, and the rhyming was good too..

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid thank you, again. I am actually going to edit just one other thing to make it rhyme a little better... annd done :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it:

> Clown?

My prefix can rip and tear, pointy or curled,
Where ours mainly grip unless werewolves exist.

> Claw

My suffix is greener in one perfect world.
Some yellow is seen, where some gardens consist.

> lawn

My infix has rules unlike the underworld.
It governs like schools; do not break or resist!

> law

And now change the vowel to between the IP.
Or throw in the towel, but that works if you see.

> Here is the part that tells us to change the A to O, and you get -> clown :)

Comment: Yes, you got the answer! Everything is correct... but where is the infix explanation? Also, there is another explanation for the "throw in the towel" part, which I am sure you would figure out, as your main explanation for the last verse is correct.

Comment: Oh, sry, forgot to write, I'm editing it! Done ^^

Comment: I'm guessing  the Infix is ROT13(ynj)

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid yes, that is correct, too :P

Comment: Riley Riddles are past me now. Back to normal, hahah. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$